# Design calculations for LVDC grid

Tags: power, dc, parallel, loss, microgrid

I'm looking to use 60 V to create a small LVDC grid to power up some small loads - 12/24/48 V maximum. For the purpose of this question I will assume 12 V only loads.

60 VDC will be the power supplied from a central location and transmitted over a 3-pair copper cable (1 mm² / 17 AWG). I want to connect some loads up in parallel - and they will be powered via a 12V DC/DC converter. I will factor in around 10/15 % for losses/inefficiencies for this converter.

I want to figure out theoretically how many loads/devices I can connect to this 60 VDC bus and over what distances. If I have one load say connected at 50 m and another at 100 m how can I represent these mathematically? I could represent the load as a resistor using its input voltage (12 V) and the max current draw by the device - and add them in parallel? I understand these loads are most likely not purely resistive however so am wondering how accurate this approach would be?

I am a bit unsure with this approach in how I represent the loads as resistors given that they will run on 12 V as opposed to the 60 VDC the power supply is providing (of course there will be losses at this point). I could take the power draw of the load (15 W), add some headroom for inefficiencies in the DC/DC down-converter to give a load of 20 W - and figure out a resistance value using the voltage supplied?

I understand that in this scenario, the current will split off at the first load - so most of the losses will be when the full current is going between the power supply and the first node/load.

Edit: Trying to work out how I can workout how much current each load will draw, because the supply voltage is different to the required voltage and also there will be a voltage drop to each load.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but have you considered using tried and tested 120 or 230 VAC instead?

Comment: _"If I have one load say connected at 50 m and another at 100 m how can I represent these mathematically?"_ Depends on how much losses you can tolerate and how hot you are comfortable running your cables. Start with 10 % voltage drop and calculate how much that gets you?

Comment: You should treat the DC-DC converter as a *constant-power* load. If the cable voltage drop is small then you can approximate it as constant-current or constant-resistance. If it's large, then not.

Comment: @winny I want to use the battery/renewable sources I have - and not convert DC to AC before converting AC back to DC again. I want to know how I can work out the equivalent resistance of these loads mathematically so I can draw out on diagram and work out max loads

Comment: @BrandonKellett DC-DC converters are not resistances. The equation you need is P=IV

Comment: @user253751 while this might be true the loads they are powering could be considered as such? I don't see how the power equation really helps here as the current will be dependant on the load - and also the voltage supplied to the DC/DC converter will have some drop associated with it

Comment: You are converting from DC to DC and then from DC back to DC again, so not much difference but you can't use normal power supplies. Also, fusing and breaking 230 VAC is trivial. Fusing and breaking 60 VDC is certainly possible, but far less common so you will have more struggle there. Simplest way I can think of is what @user253751 said, assume an equivalent resistance, calculate the voltage drop and recompute for that. Should get you close enough. I would try to get <10 % drop for economy. Keep in mind your thermals from the cable dissipation.

Comment: @BrandonKellett What are they powering? Resistive loads?

Comment: @winny there are a lot of differences. 60V DC is classed as LVDC whereas 230VAC is not (safety). My power source is already 60VDC so I am only performing one DC/DC conversion versus two. Breaking the 60VDC is fine as I have appropriate rated breakers to hand. I can develop an equivalent resistance using the 12VDC rating of the load plus its current as per it's datasheet to obtain an equivalent resistance. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @user253751 network gear such as CCTV, switches, access points - all with DC input

Comment: Good, you have thought though this. Yes, your 12 V load (W), divided by the efficiency of your 60->12 V converter, divided with your 60 V end-of-line voltage (I assumed 54 V here), gives you the current. A sanity check would be to calculate the actual voltage drop across the cable (both ways) from said current. If less than 6 V, you should be fine.

Comment: @winny so for multiple loads connected in parallel at significant distances - how do I extend this method? The wire between loads will act as a resistance. This can be combined with the respective load in parallel. Repeat for each load?

Comment: By simulation. Section your DC line in reasonable intervals, say 5 meter, with calculated cable resistance for each section. Add your source and as many loads as you have. Press run. Get results. ????. Profit.

Comment: Is it best to add cable resistance as one lumped resistance or one half for "forward path" and one for "return path" as shown: https://imgur.com/vpTQEYm
@winny

Comment: @BrandonKellett Yes, as I said. 5 meter is just an arbitrary measurement depending on where you have your loads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are powering a 12V load with some nominal current, through a DC/DC converter.

The DC/DC converter will maintain its output at 12V no matter what, and deliver the current demanded by the load. Let's suppose it's 1A for example.

The DC/DC converter will output 12V 1A, or 12W. Add some margin for the converter's inefficiency, and it may draw 15W from its input side.

The converter will have to accept the voltage given to it, and will draw however much current it needs to make up 15W. If the voltage is 60V, it will draw 0.25A. If the voltage drops to 30V, it will draw 0.5A, **not** 0.125A. **It's not resistive** and no amount of denial, anger, bargaining or depression will make it resistive.

You can *approximate* it as resistive, if the voltage doesn't vary too much. If you absolutely need a resistance for some calculation, and you guesstimate the voltage is definitely at least 50V, then the current will be 0.3A at most, which means the resistance is 50V/0.3A = 166.67 ohms **or higher**. If your design works out with a resistance of 166.67 ohms **or higher**, then when the voltage is actually 60V, and the effective resistance is 60V/0.2A = 300 ohms, your design will still work.

But if you can, it's better to just **not pretend** that this non-resistive load is resistive. Use the constant-power equation, \$I=\frac PV\$ instead of the constant-resistance equation, \$I=\frac VR\$. Series/parallel resistance laws won't work, but mesh analysis still works, and you won't have to make conservative estimates.

Note the maths can find more than one equilibrium state. Suppose the source voltage is 50V and cable resistance is 10 ohms. A constant-power load might be able to pull 2A at 30V (causing 20A voltage drop), or 3A at 20V (causing 30A voltage drop). The former is stable, and the latter is unstable as it would collapse to either the stable state or 0 volts. I don't *think* you have to worry about those inefficient equilibrium states, provided you have enough capacity to power everything, but I'm not sure.

Comment: So I can simulate as such to test:

https://imgur.com/vpTQEYm

This shows I can power 3 separate 15W loads at varying distances. The horizontal resistors are representing the cable resistance - I used 17AWG at lengths of 200m, 375m and 200m.